# Censor time-dependent Cox proportional

Tags: cox-model, censoring

I am conducting a study to check whether a drug causes fractures, and I am using time dependent Cox PH model.

My question is regarding the follow-up time when stratifying. Let's say that we want to look at any fracture and then stratify by location of fracture e.g. hip, knee, elbow...

First we want to look at all fractures combined. Assume we have a patient who suffers any given fracture on period 10, therefore, we censor him at this time. However, when we want to look into stratified by location e.g. knee, shall we censor him at time 10 although he might not have had a knee fracture or just we censor at the end of his follow-up?

I cannot find a convincing answer and I find arguments supporting censoring at the time any fracture happens, but also to censor at the end of follow up.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this would be to specify a different event label for each fracture location that you want to examine. The `Surv()` function in the R `survival` package allows for categorical `event` labels, provided that (fully) censored is the reference level. You aren't limited to 0/1 censored/event labeling. That provides a good deal of flexibility.

When you do a survival analysis for time to fracture, specify a logical FALSE/TRUE event value that describes the particular location or combination of locations that you want to evaluate as the event for that analysis. Those for whom the logical value is FALSE will be treated as censored *for that analysis* but will still be available for other analyses.

This also allows repeated-event or multi-state models of fractures within individuals if you include an appropriate `ID` value on each data row. See the [multi-state model vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) for an introduction.